# make 'each' cycles occur consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have two actions I need to apply to a set of DIV's, but I need one cycle to happen before the other is finished.

Here is my code:

```
$("div").each(function(){
        //do stuff first
}).each(function(){
        //do stuff next
});
```

but at present, `do stuff next` happens before `do stuff first` finishes. Anything I can do to stop this?

**Full Script**

```
$("div").each(function(){
                    if($(this).html() === "yes"){

                        $(this).fadeOut(time,function(){
                            $(this).parent().height(0);
                        });



                    }
        }).each(function(){
                    if($(this).html() !== "yes"){

                        $(this).parent().height(25);
                        $(this).fadeIn(time);

                    }
        });
```

Comment: The `stuff` you're doing `first` might be asynchronous, and in that case you'll probably have to use a callback.

Comment: using the `fadeIn` and `height`

Comment: No time to go into more detail but look at jQuery's `queue()`.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz, `fadeIn()` is asynchronous. Use its callback argument and chain into the `next stuff` from there. (As always, post more of your code to get better answers.)

Comment: just posted the full thing. The problem there is I have several fadeIn/Out's in each block that I need to happen together.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz, please fix your question to be animation-specific if that's what you mean.  The first part of your question is a generic jQuery programming question that can have a very different answer than if what you're doing in the block is starting an animation and you want something else to start when the animation is done.  As it's currently written your question is ambiguous at best.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you want to fadeIn and then set height, will this do what you require?

```
var divs = $('div');
divs.fadeIn(function () {
  divs.height('200');
});
```

Using each to allow different settings for different divs:

```
$('div').each(function () {
  var div = $(this), toggle = true;
  div.fadeIn(function () {
    if (toggle = !toggle) {
      div.height('200');
    } else {
      div.width('200');
    }
  });
});
```

Seeing your code snippet I believe I got it now:

```
var yesDivs = $('div').filter(function () {
  return $(this).html() === 'yes';
});
yesDivs.fadeOut(time, function () {
  yesDivs.parent().height(0);
  $('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() !== 'yes';
  }).fadeIn(time).parent().height(25);
});
```

Comment: you can easily modify this to use each.

Comment: but you've grouped the fadeIn and heights into two camps. this is not the intended action as the script shows.

Comment: Check out my latest code. I believe I now understand what you want.